# What is the best data store for sorting large data

Tags: mysql, sorting, nosql

I have millions (30-100 millions) of records with multiple columns. I need to sort this data on multiple columns and display them in pages. What is the best way to store this data?

Let us say if there is a table with columns T(id, c1,c2 ... cn). In MYSQL this query looks something like this:

select id from T order by cx, cy limit 1000, 1000

I can assume it is a read only table, but I need fast response.

Is there any advantage for this problem with NoSQL databases?

Comment: all the nosql fans. please!!! it s not a silver bullet. If you have a solid architecture and design. mysql should be fine with 100 millions of records. that s nothing. if your design is not good, nosql not even jesus christ can save you.

Comment: Please let me know if there is any good design or best practice in this scenario. All I need is a sorted order using one or more columns from a dozen columns in one big table.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables are properly indexed it would be fairly quick, even with millions or records. When you start adding conditions, like WHERE some_date < now() table partitioning might also help, but you have to plan ahead to fit partitions to your needs, otherwise it might slow it down instead.

NoSQL advantages are speed and flexible schema, but with millions of records it will require a significant amount of memory, plus in some cases like Redis it will require to have 50% of memory available for forking when it writes to disk etc. Is the response you are getting now not fast enough? Are your queries hitting correct indexes?

Comment: With MYSQL, it is not using the index if there are multiple columns in order by clause. File sort is taking time.